# Kotlin setText Phone Field

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin and at the same time writing small app and I have a problem with set text on Phone field, probably I must format this in other way but I do not know how. Please help

```
var phoneNumber: String = ""
```

after this I load the data

```
fun loadData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        phoneNumber = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "")!!
        println(phoneNumber)
    }
```

and here I got simple string eg. 878546342

then

```
fun updateViews() {
        phoneEditField.text = phoneNumber
    }
```

this underline me phoneNumber so I know something is wrong, but I do not know what

when I use

```
fun updateViews() {
        phoneEditField.setText(phoneNumber)
    }
```

there is no underline but app crash after call this function

here is XML

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneEditField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

EDIT 1
here is a error message

```
I/System.out: 878546342
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.idea98komunikator, PID: 6862
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idea98komunikator/com.example.idea98komunikator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.idea98komunikator.MainActivity.updateViews(MainActivity.kt:118)
        at com.example.idea98komunikator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: `but app crash after call this function` show error log

Comment: check your import. Maybe import wrong xml?

Comment: Your `phoneEditField` is null. You cannot set text to null view.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.idea98komunikator/com.example.idea98komunikator.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
> object reference

**REASON**

- At first make sure you, declare **`EditText`**:

```
val phoneEditField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneEditField)
```

- Check  **`phoneNumber`** is null or not:

```
fun updateViews() {
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber.toString())) {
        phoneEditField.setText(phoneNumber.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer will prevent crash, but this does not really address the reason for the `EditText` being null.

Comment: @RakibulIslam Oh. then must declare

Comment: I've edited your answer to make it more meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Here the stack trace clearly say,

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.idea98komunikator.MainActivity.updateViews(MainActivity.kt:118)
```

The issue is not with your String variable **phoneNumber**. But with your text field **phoneEditField**. Have you inititalized your EditTextField in your class?

To fix this, open your Activity class and in **onCreate** function add.

```
val phoneEditField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneEditField)
```

After that use *setText* function in phoneEditField.

```
phoneEditField.setText(phoneNumber)
```

As *phoneEditField.text* need an Editable, not a String.

Please let me know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help but, proposed solutions doesn't work for me.
Probably it's my out of knowledge of android studio and kotlin.
I solved my problem just setText() after dialog with this phoneEditField shows.

```
fun showDialog() {
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout)
        val phoneField  = dialog.findViewById(R.id.phoneEditField) as EditText
        phoneField.setText(phoneNumber)
```

}

And not like before was in my plan -> loadData - > setText() phoneEditField -> in other fun open dialog

Answer (score -1):

Check the import of `kotlinx.android.synthetic.your_actviy_name`

and make sure you references the right XML that contains  `phoneEditField`